# document.activeElement for react native

Tags: react-native

I'm porting an app from web to React Native. A certain component uses `document.activeElement` to quickly get the currently focused field and then run some logic on it. I'm finding it very hard to quickly do the same on React Native; all I find online tells me to use `ref`s, which would add LOTS of complexity as I'd have to customize lots of components and sprinkle refs all around + manage them, when all I want is a non-intrusive way to find out where the user has focus.

My current iteration is storing the selected field during `onFocus` event, which is also not ideal as I have to handle events and store one more variable, which by next render cycle can be stale.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer (my) original question, but it did solve my problem.

Turns out I was trying to use web logic to a problem that React deals with another way; I could just do the same on my React JS app and it would probably work too.

Trying to get *the* active element among all, compare it with the last element I touched and all, is a big burden and adds a lot of complexity. I found a third-party component I use has an `autoFocus` prop and played with it. When it worked, I just added the same prop to my other custom components, and lo and behold, it got the job done with much less complexity and better encapsulation.

Lesson learned: think outside the box, but keep things in their own boxes ;)